# Problems moving J25 to new server

Tags: joomla-2.5, migration

I'm unable to move Joomla! 2.5.4 to another server.

Having built my Joomla site on my local machine, when I upload the site to the live environment (having updated the DB and corrected the settings in configuration.php) Joomla generates this error message when I try to reach the admin console.

> Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir
>   restriction in effect.
>   File(/path/to/administrator/defines.php) is not
>   within the allowed path(s): (/Library/WebServer/Documents:tmp) in
>   /path/to/administrator/index.php on line 12
>
> Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: open_basedir
>   restriction in effect.
>   File(/path/to/administrator/includes/defines.php)
>   is not within the allowed path(s): (/Library/WebServer/Documents:tmp)
>   in /path/to/administrator/index.php on line 18
>
> Warning:
>   require_once(/path/to/administrator/includes/defines.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Operation not
>   permitted in /path/to/administrator/index.php
>   on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required
>   '/path/to/administrator/includes/defines.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /path/to/administrator/index.php on line 18

The installation is looking for the old path even though I have changed public $log_path and public $tmp_path to the new path in configuration.php

Comment: Take a look at Akeba backup as a way of moving sites in future

Comment: If you have not changed the path to pasted it here "/path/to/administrator/includes/defines.php" is likely to be the path in a tutorial or config that needs updating to your own path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would disable `open_basedir`, it tends to generate more problems than it solves.

If you need it, make sure the administrator folder is in the allowed paths.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on the Joomla Site: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=710302

Finally got it... I was reading about the "open_basedir" directive. "

Did a locate php.ini and there it was: /home/xxxxx/htdocs/xxxxxxx.net/administrator/php.ini

If you have a php.ini file in this location, change the following two items to the correct paths:

```
upload_tmp_dir = your path here
open_basedir = your path here
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update or remove a `RewriteBase` statement in the `.htaccess` file in the root folder of your website.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen before on a couple of sites.  The first cause is one that is already mentioned with .htaccess/apache config issue.

The other cause I've seen is a caching problem.  Try turning off the cache via manually changing the option in the /configuration.php file.  You can also manually delete everything in the /cache directory except the index.html file.

Hope this helps.